# a thousandS years tradition

Tags: expressions, grammatical-number

> A thousand**s** year old tradition

"a thousand year old" tradition, would mean only a 1000 years, but I'm not sure we could use the plural form in this expression.

I'm looking for an adjective that would means several thousand years.

"ancient" would NOT be precise enough

Answer (score 5):

> It’s a tradition thousands of years old.
>
> It’s a several–thousand-year-old tradition.
>
> It’s a many–thousand-year-old tradition.
>
> It has been a tradition for thousands of years.

You could also use the adjective *multi-millenial*, but that sounds more formal/literary.

Comment: thanks! And what do you think about Sam answer "millennia-old"?

Answer (score 4):

A millenium is an era of a thousand years. Its plural form is millenia, so "millenia-old" is one possibility.